# AVIdemux python script not working

Tags: python

I have this AVIdemux python script but i don't know how to say where to save my files.

I don't know what i should put in the adm.save() field. i want to save it with source filename

```
gui=Gui()
adm=Avidemux()

ext="mp4"
sep = "\\"
dir = "C:\\result\\"

inputFolder = gui.dirSelect("Select the source folder")
#
def convert(filein):  
    adm.loadVideo("C:\\doc\\Intro 1080p pfr.mp4")
    if(0 == adm.appendVideo(filein)):
        ui.displayError("oops","cannot load "+filein)
        raise

    adm.videoCodec("copy")
    adm.audioClearTracks()
    adm.setSourceTrackLanguage(0,"unknown")
    adm.audioAddTrack(0)
    adm.audioCodec(0, "copy")
    adm.audioSetDrc(0, 0)
    adm.audioSetShift(0, 0,0)
    adm.setContainer("MP4V2", "optimize=0", "add_itunes_metadata=0")
    adm.save(dir + basename)
    print("Done")

#
# Main
#

list=get_folder_content(inputFolder,ext)

if(list is None):
    raise
for i in list:
        convert(i)
print("Done")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put :

```
adm.save(dir + "/" + basename(filein))
```

This will save the video in `%dir%/video_name.mp4` whatever your dir is. If you want your dir not to be static, you can put :

```
destinationFolder = gui.dirSelect("Select the source folder")
```

next your inputFolder and then use :

```
adm.save(destinationFolder + "/" + basename(filein))
```

This was your destinationFolder will be whatever you select.